# Use Rest Doc to document Rest APIs with versioning

Tags: rest, versioning, spring-restdocs

I am using Rest Doc to document my Rest APIs. Based on the TestNg methods I generate the snippets that, later on, I use in the asciidoc.

For example, I have a rest endpoint to retrieve people, and also the TestNg method to document it. So then, I can use it in my ascii doc like this:

```
=== Get People

Get the people registered.

operation::get-people[snippets='http-request,request-fields,http-response,response-fields,error-codes']
```

But now, my API changed, and I introduced versioning, so the API is different from version 1 to version 2. I also want to document that properly, but I don't know how to do it by being the "less intrusive" possible.

I would like my documentation to have this structure

Resources
  v1
    getPeople
  v2
    getPeople

For the API that really change from one version to another I need to generate a different snippet per version the api support, since maybe the request fields or response fields are different.

But, I also have some other rest endpoints that has the same API from one version to another, and I think that I also need to generate the snippets for each version since the version is part of the rest endpoint path.

Do you have any idea on how to being able to add versioning to the rest docs?